# .NET Core 3.1 Azure AD Authentication interceptor

Tags: .net, authentication, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I have  a .NET Core 3.1 web app using Azure AD for Authentication and and it is working correctly with the following source code.

```
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
```

Now I want to add an interceptor that tells me if the authentication was successful.
I want to record the login in file, database or whatever.
How can i carry out this process?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`events`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/Events/OpenIdConnectEvents.cs) of `OpenIDConnectOptions`. [`OnUserInformationReceived`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents.onuserinformationreceived?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_OpenIdConnect_OpenIdConnectEvents_OnUserInformationReceived) is invoked when user information is retrieved from the UserInfoEndpoint. It is executed once on successful login.

```
options.Events.OnUserInformationReceived = ctx =>
{
    // your code here
    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```